# How to save an Excel file via ssms or c# in a SQL Server 2016 database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, excel, ssms

I'm trying to save an existing Excel file via ssms OR C# into my SQL Server 2016 database.

I want to save each row of my Excel file in a C# object and then save it into my database, or do you have better ideas?

I also thought about saving the Excel file as a `*.csv` and import this file via ssms in my database.

Which of these two ideas would you recommend or is there any other way to solve this problem?

If you have any questions, I would be pleased to answer them.

I thank you in advance for all the answers and tips!

Comment: Please read the [help] before asking. This question could be closed for at least two reasons. No effort given to solve your problem and asking for recommendations.

Comment: the answer depends too much on size of spreadsheet.. do your own test runs decide which works best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your problem you can try below approaches:

**1) Using SQLBulkcopy:**

SqlBulkCopy class as the name suggests does the bulk insert from one source to another and hence all rows from the Excel sheet can be easily read and inserted using the SqlBulkCopy class.

```
protected void Upload(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Upload and save the file
    string excelPath = Server.MapPath("~/Files/") + Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    FileUpload1.SaveAs(excelPath);

    string conString = string.Empty;
    string extension = Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName);
    switch (extension)
    {
        case ".xls": //Excel 97-03
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel03ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;
        case ".xlsx": //Excel 07 or higher
            conString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Excel07+ConString"].ConnectionString;
            break;

    }
    conString = string.Format(conString, excelPath);
    using (OleDbConnection excel_con = new OleDbConnection(conString))
    {
        excel_con.Open();
        string sheet1 = excel_con.GetOleDbSchemaTable(OleDbSchemaGuid.Tables, null).Rows[0]["TABLE_NAME"].ToString();
        DataTable dtExcelData = new DataTable();

        //[OPTIONAL]: It is recommended as otherwise the data will be considered as String by default.
        dtExcelData.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id", typeof(int)),
                new DataColumn("Name", typeof(string)),
                new DataColumn("Salary",typeof(decimal)) });

        using (OleDbDataAdapter oda = new OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [" + sheet1 + "]", excel_con))
        {
            oda.Fill(dtExcelData);
        }
        excel_con.Close();

        string consString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(consString))
        {
            using (SqlBulkCopy sqlBulkCopy = new SqlBulkCopy(con))
            {
                //Set the database table name
                sqlBulkCopy.DestinationTableName = "dbo.tblPersons";

                //[OPTIONAL]: Map the Excel columns with that of the database table
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Id", "PersonId");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Name", "Name");
                sqlBulkCopy.ColumnMappings.Add("Salary", "Salary");
                con.Open();
                sqlBulkCopy.WriteToServer(dtExcelData);
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here this code adds an excel sheet with three columns as Id, Name and Salary.

**2) Using DTS in SSMS:**

You can use the SQL Server Data Transformation Services (DTS) Import Wizard or the SQL Server Import and Export Wizard to import Excel data into SQL Server tables. When you are stepping through the wizard and selecting the Excel source tables, remember that Excel object names that are appended with a dollar sign ($) represent worksheets (for example, Sheet1$), and that plain object names without the dollar sign represent Excel named ranges.

**3) Using SSIS package:**

You can create SSIS package to import excel file. For this, you can use BIDS in Visual Studio or SQL Server Data tools.

You can give your excel file as excel source and in the target give your SQL server database table.
Perform the necessary mappings and you're good to go.

Now, you must be having a question like When to use which approach?

Use approach 1, Whenever you're providing functionality to import excel file at the user end, i.e. according to application requirement, the user can upload local excel sheet. For this use case, one thing you should look out is, the user must be aware of the template. If you have written code to import excel with 3 columns and the user tries to import with 4 columns, you will have some error in future. So make sure that you provide a template that user should download and fill and upload it.

Use approach 2, whenever you want to load data for only one time, or you can say that you want to perform initial load. You can use this approach as it's most simple and requires less time to do the configuration.

Use approach 3, whenever you have some requirement like to import excel data on the timely basis from some shared location. For ex, you are importing monthly mobile bills to your database provided by some vendor. You can create a package for this functionality and do the SSIS configuration and create a package.
Once the package is created you can create a SQL job and schedule it as per the requirements.

Comment: Thank you so much for your detailed answer! Approach 3 seems interesting for me and I hope this will be the solution for my problem! Again, many thanks for your efforts!

Comment: You're welcome. While using Approach 3, make sure you use data conversion functionalities while importing, otherwise, you'll have erroneous data. Please let me know in case you require any help on it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BulkInsert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql) to imports a data file into a database table or view in a user-specified format in SQL Server

Comment: Thanks! I'll give it a try!

Answer (score 0):

As all, it depends on usage, change frequency, who is going to maintain solution etc.

**SSIS and CSV import**

It is possible to create SSIS package which would be able to import your data automatically when deployed on MSSQL server or manually. This would be simplest/quickest to implement. One of advantages when using Visual Studio tooling for SSIS development you would have visual representation of mappings, flow.
Drawback, even though I have seen automated column mapping updates (C# automatic SSIS package generation), whenever you would need to add, remove, change column, you would need a manual change.

**BCP**

MS console utility which you can use to define columns in format files and import your CSVs. Drawback is that you there is no graphical user interface, though many would argue that this is an advantage because there is a better overview for changes.

**ORM**

In object relational mapping solution you would need to translate your Excel file into object oriented programming language classes and save as objects into database table. Drawback is that you need to have some programming knowledge, but would pay off in a longer run because potentially your solution could get the data directly form source for those excel sheets.